# How to return the full object once it`s been found?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So starting from an array of objects I need to find if any of them are called Google. If so I need to return the full object. Now It is returning `true`

```
const companies = [ { id: 1, username: 'facebook', website: 'www.facebook.com' }, { id: 2, username: 'google', website: 'www.google.com' }, { id: 3, username: 'linkedin', website: 'www.linkedin.com' } ]
const checkCompany = company => company.name === "google";

console.log(companies.some(checkCompany)); // true
```

Comment: does it work? your objects hav different properties than in the callback. do you have only one object that matches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) returns a `Boolean`.You can use [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which returns the **value of first element** in array. If no element in array matches condition then it returns `undefined`

```js
const companies = [ { id: 1, username: 'facebook', website: 'www.facebook.com' }, { id: 2, username: 'google', website: 'www.google.com' }, { id: 3, username: 'linkedin', website: 'www.linkedin.com' } ]
const res = companies.find(x => x.username === "google");
console.log(res)
```